# python matrix of functions

Tags: python, function, numpy, matrix

Given the two matrices f and x:

```
def f11(x): return 1
def f12(x): return x+1
def f21(x): return np.log(x)
def f22(x): return np.exp(x)


f = np.matrix([[f11,f12],[f21,f22]])
x = np.matrix([[10,5],[3,8]])
```

How can I apply element-wise the matrix operator f to x (considering that the functions may be more complex, so it's just an example)?

Answer (score 1):

Matrices are basically not designed to support such functionalities. Instead you can use one function that accepts an array and returns the expected result. The reason that you should use array instead of matrix is that they're more flexible and better adoptable with python operations, like in this case in-place unpacking.

```
In [41]: def apply_f(matrix):
    ...:     ((x, y), (z, t)) = matrix
    ...:     return np.array([[1, y +1], [np.log(z), np.exp(t)]])
    ...: 

In [42]: x = np.array([[3, 5], [10, 8]])

In [43]: apply_f(x)
Out[43]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 6.00000000e+00],
       [2.30258509e+00, 2.98095799e+03]])
```